# Chemical potential and condition for equilibrium in case of binary liquid reaction mixture

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, liquids

Suppose there is a liquid mixture with components A and B in equilibrium along with their vapours. Then with the Gibbs-Duhem equation we know that $$μ_A(\mathrm{liquid}) = μ_A(\mathrm{vapor})$$ and
$$μ_B(\mathrm{liquid}) = μ_B(\mathrm{vapor})$$
But then imagine a case where A(liquid) is getting converted to B(liquid), so for that case $$d G = - μ_A(\mathrm{liquid})\cdot dn+μ_B(\mathrm{liquid})\cdot dn$$ (for this reaction), so if $μ_A(\mathrm{liquid})$ is not equal to $μ_B(\mathrm{liquid})$, then this reaction will take place in one of the directions.

So doesn't it mean that $μ_A(\mathrm{liquid})$  must also be equal to $μ_B(\mathrm{liquid})$?

Comment: Reference for chem equation/expression formatting:
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation)  /  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  /  
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)  // [For more:  Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  // Not to be applied in CH SE titles.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Are the liquids miscible?

Comment: The name is Duhem. Please use mathjax to edit math expressions and mhchem for chemical expressions. See the first comment and help section for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does, if stoichiometric coefficients are the same.

For eventual reaction of 2 volatile miscible liquids $\ce{A}$ and $\ce{B}$

$$\ce{A <=> B}$$

all the respective chemical potentials must be equal, otherwise the system would not be at the Gibbs function minimum:

$$\mu(\ce{A(g)})=\mu(\ce{A(sol)})=\mu(\ce{B(sol)})=\mu(\ce{B(g)})$$

Answer (score 1):

> Then with gibbs durhem eqn we know that μA(liquid) = μA(vapor) μB(liquid) = μB(vapor).

That is not Gibbs/Duhem equation. Gibbs/Duhem equation states a restriction between activity coefficients at constant $P$ and $T$ must satisfy, this is, $\sum_j x_j d\ln(\gamma_j) = 0$. What you have written is the condition of chemical equilibrium of species between diferent phases.

> But then imagine a case where A(liquid) is getting converted to B(liquid) so for that case Delta G = - μA(liquid)*dn+μB(liquid)*dn. (for this reaction),

We need to address how the chemical potentials are related between each other in this case. This is a bit more difficult than usual, because we have a reaction but two phases, i.e., a heterogeneous system. The main idea is that **we can separate** (1) the chemical reaction, and (2) the conventional chemical equilibria. This is not so straightforward to prove, but I will show what happens in this case.

First, lets apply the Gibbs phase rule for reacting systems, so we know how many relationships we need
\begin{align}
  F &= 2 - \pu{Num. of phases} + \pu{Num. of components} - \pu{Num. of chemical reactions} \\
  F &= 2 - 2 + 2 - 1 \rightarrow \boxed{F=1}
\end{align}
because we have two components ($A$ and $B$), two phases (liquid and vapor), and one chemical reaction.

The chemical reaction that you proposed, that we can generalize
$$ \ce{aA (l)} \rightarrow \ce{bB (l)} $$
gives us one condition that must be satisfied **in the liquid phase** ($a$ and $b$ are positive)
$$ \sum_j \nu_j \mu_j^L = 0 \rightarrow
    \boxed{-a\mu_A^L(P,T,x_A) + b\mu_B^L(P,T,x_B) = 0} \tag{1} $$
The other two, are simply the conditions of chemical equilibrium for species in a closed system

$$ \boxed{\mu_A^V(P,T,y_A) = \mu_A^L(P,T,x_A)} \hspace{1 cm}
   \boxed{\mu_B^V(P,T,y_B) = \mu_B^L(P,T,x_B)} \tag{2,3} $$

Eqs. (1-3) are the relationships we need to solve the system. The number of intensive variables are **four**:

1. The pressure $P$ [mechanical equilibrium implies $(P^V=P^L=P)$].
2. The temperature $T$ [thermal equilibrium implies $(T^V=T^L=T)$].
3. Two molar fractions, since the other one can be calculated with $y_B = 1 - y_A$ and $x_B = 1 - x_A$.

And the number of equations are **three**, so everything is fine.